# Initialize values in Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a dll that exposes Interface which looks like this:

```
public Interface IClientGroup
{
    IQueryable ClientsGroup {get;}
    void Activate(ClientGroup clientgroup);

    //many other members and functions
}
```

In my controller class, it is passed in constructor like this:

```
public ControllerClass(IClientGroup clientgroup)
{
     var _clientgroup = clientgroup
}

//later _clientgroup used to access everything in Interface
```

Now when I debug I see that it while it is passed to contructor, the values are already initialized, so I assume I can simply pass `IClientgroup clientgroup` in any function and it will be already initialized but it is null, everytime if I declare it before using and says `it is type but used as variable` if I diectly pass to a function as done in consturctor.

```
public UseValues(IclientGroup clientgroup)
{
     //error: IClientGroup is type but used as variable
}
```

How do I use the clientgroup with values initialized? I can't see exact implementations from dll.

Comment: `var _clientgroup = clientgroup` initializes local variale inside the ctor, you won't be able to reuse it in other places in the class. Use a private field or a property for that

Comment: This is pretty much OOP 101. You might want to take some time to step back and learn a little basic object-oriented programming before diving too deeply into this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public ControllerClass(IClientGroup clientgroup)
{
  var _clientgroup = clientgroup
}
```

Above code stores the `clientgroup` parameter in to local variable, not the instance field. You need to store it in a instance field in order to use it later.

```
class ControllerClass
{
    private IClientGroup _clientgroup;
    public ControllerClass(IClientGroup clientgroup)
    {
       if(clientgroup == null)
       {
           //Don't allow null values
           throw new ArgumentNullException("clientgroup");
       }
       this._clientgroup = clientgroup
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        //Use this._clientgroup here
    }
}
```

Apart from question you really need a [beginner tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners)

Comment: I understand that question is trivial.Sorry for asking again but the clientgroup is to be used in some other class(test class actually) and it doesn't seem to be initialized with values there. I can't use `this._clientGroup` there.

Comment: No, this points to current instance(ControllerClass here) you can't access it in other class. If you need to use, you make a public property of type `IClientGroup` and use `controllerClassInstance.ClientGroupProperty`. Again please go through basics..